# Caching data and databindings - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just trying to get my head around how to structure this one.

I have some components that all need the same data. So I've defined a service (.factory) that provides access to that data. However if I then need to update the data I'm breaking all the bindings.

I've made a failure of a plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XiQy17Jv1eNIp3IOl1ig) (any idea what I've missed out?) but you can see my meaning in the code which follows:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory("userState", function($scope)
{
  $scope.settings = {};

  $scope.update = function(data)
  {
    $scope.settings = data;
  };

  return {
            getSettings: function(){
                return $scope.settings;
            },
            updateData: function(data){
              $scope.update(data);
            },
            initialise: function(){
              var simulatingTheFirstAjaxCall = {};
              simulatingTheFirstAjaxCall.property = "hello world!";
              $scope.update(simulatingTheFirstAjaxCall);
            }
         };
});
app.controller("IndexController", function($scope, userState)
{
  userState.initialise();
  $scope.settings = userState.getSettings();

  $scope.simulateSecondAjaxCall = function()
  {
    var object = {};
    object.property = "goodbye world";
    userState.updateData(object);
  };
});
```

There are a few solutions in my head but none of them seem satisfactory. Dynamically copying properties can run into issues (arrays, dates, custom objects, etc), having all the components query the datasource themselves is very chatty, directly binding to the service just feels wrong. Maybe I should just always return an object that has a .data property which is the only thing I change..... idk it seems silly and like I'm missing something fundamental.

I'd love to make some sort of dynamic property decorator ($scope.settings.inner = data;) but i'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Why do you have '$scope' inside your factory?

Comment: I had the impression it was just a place to put things for every kind of object. I'm new to javascript too.

Comment: No, the way I understand it $scope is just the glue between your controller and your view. i.e. if you declare something on $scope you can access/edit it from your view. The scope varaible in @marcoseu 's service has no relation to the $scope in any controller. Although it technically works, I wouldn't name it scope as it could leave to confusion. Once again, there is no concept of $scope inside services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems in your plunker:

1. You are referencing $scope in your factory, which will not get injected.  If you must use $scope, pass it during initialization
2. You are not bootstraping angular: you need to add `ng-app="app"` in your index.html

Here is modified working version of your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/B2NRza?p=preview

Having said that, it should be clarified the use of `scope` in a factory or a service singleton is used to facilitate setting of property or invoking a method in a form/controller.  The data should stored in a private variable in the singleton instead of the `scope`.  The updated plunker above is a quick fix to your question.  In a real world app, `$scope` should be stored in an array, and removed when scope is destroyed using:

`scope.$on('$destroy', function () {...})`

Here is a sample Alert Services that demonstrate use of `$scope` in a service:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rQaWnmbvYFhm5htCXAAc?p=preview

Comment: I like how you solved the problem. You passed the scope into the service. That was a solution I had not considered. Now this means what I can do is make all controllers that want some data pass in their scope to the service, the service can store these in an array and whenever the data updates it can set the new value on every scope. Is that a good solution?

Comment: That is certainly a possibility but if all you need is a single cached property, you can consider storing the cached value in $rootScope.  If you decide to store scope in an array, you must use `scope.$on('$destroy', function () {...})` to remove the scope that is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes it would be a common theme to the architecture. The application doesn't have multiple users changing the same online dataset (just their own specific ones) so its a rare case where its viable to cache everything. The destroy tip is golden, thank you. :)

Comment: I would like to add that's generally considered bad practice to put stuff inside $rootScope. Factories and services are singletons so storing stuff inside them will have the same effect as using $rootScope but it might avoid naming conflicts and will generally make your Angular code more understandable.

Comment: Yes, I don't intend to touch $rootScope.

Comment: Updated answer with more detail and added another plunker based on the discussion that has taken place.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're using `$scope` inside your factory which doesn't make sense and you shouldn't do. Instead, have something like this.

```
app.factory('userState', [function(){
   return {
      setting1: true,
      setting2: false
   }
}]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'userState', function($scope, userState){
   $scope.userState=userState;
   $scope.updateSettings= function(){
      //e.g. change one setting to false, will also update factory value
      $scope.userState.setting1=false;
   }
}]);
```

Since in JavaScript non-primitive objects are passed by reference, you can change `$scope.userState` and it will also change your factory.